# Sliding/Hiding Divs Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to make an accordion of sorts for my projects section of my website and I've run into a very strange issue (or maybe I'm just really tired). The first click to expand a selection works fine, but when the header is clicked again to return to the original state the contents of the previously expanded header become hidden. Furthermore, upon clicking the same header again to expand any time after the first the containing border disappears.

To see my problem in action just go to my website:

http://cole.quinnchrzan.com/cc2

and see for yourself by clicking on the projects section.

If you just want to take a look at the code here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var sign = 1;
    $('#projects > div:not(.header)').on('click', function() {
        if (sign == 1) {
            $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
            $(this).children().slideDown(400);
            $(this).siblings().slideUp(400);
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('border-bottom', '1px solid black');
            $(this).children().slideUp(400);
            $(this).siblings().slideDown(400);
            $(this).css({
                'height': '29px',
                'z-index': '2'
            });
        }
        sign = sign*-1;
    });
});
```

and the HTML:

```
<section id="projects">
    <div class="header">Websites</div>
    <div><a href="#">Saia LTL, Inc.</a>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div><a href="#">Insurance House</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Scandinavian Collectors Club</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Casey Sills Photography</a></div>
    <div class="header">Personal Projects</div>
    <div><a href="#">cTV</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">PoE DPS calculator</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">tSlide</a></div>
</section>
```

I added some extra css `'height': '29px'` `'z-index': '2'` to try and make the affected heading show again but it just creates an empty div. Without this css the div has no height.

Comment: i just noted you affect your children as well as they get the attribute hidden

Comment: I was too tired after all. Just had to add a div selector to the children()!

Comment: you can answer your question by yourself and mark it as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake. I simply forgot to select only `div` children when hiding/showing so the `a` children were remaining hidden or something. In other words I changed this:

```
$(this).children()
```

to this:

```
$(this).children('div')
```

Thanks to pfried for the indication!

Answer (score 1):

try this.

live demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8n8ga/)

**HTML**

```
<section id="projects">PROJECTS
    <div class="header">Websites</div>
    <div><a href="#">Saia LTL, Inc.</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Insurance House</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Scandinavian Collectors Club</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Casey Sills Photography</a></div>
    <div class="header">Personal Projects</div>
    <div><a href="#">cTV</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">PoE DPS calculator</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">tSlide</a></div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var sign = 1;
$('#projects > div:not(.header)').on('click', function() {
    if (sign == 1) {
        $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
        $(this).children().slideDown(400);
        $(this).siblings().slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $(this).css('border-bottom', '1px solid black');
        $(this).siblings().slideDown(400);
        $(!$(this).children(":first")).slideUp(400);
    }
    sign = sign*-1;
});
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION**

live demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXg2e/2/)

**HTML**

```
<section id="projects">PROJECTS
    <div class="header">Websites</div>
    <div><a href="#" class="ShowThis">Saia LTL, Inc.</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="ShowThis">Insurance House</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="ShowThis">Scandinavian Collectors Club</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="ShowThis">Casey Sills Photography</a></div>
    <div class="header">Personal Projects</div>
    <div><a href="#" class="ShowThis">cTV</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="ShowThis">PoE DPS calculator</a></div>
    <div><a href="#" class="ShowThis">tSlide</a></div>
</section>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var sign = 1;
$('#projects > div:not(.header) > .ShowThis').on('click', function() {
    if (sign == 1) {
        $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
        $(this).children().slideDown(400);
        $(this).parent().siblings().slideUp(400);
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().css('border-bottom', '1px solid black');
        $(this).parent().siblings().slideDown(400);        
        $(this).children().slideUp(400);
    }
    sign = sign*-1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.header div.slide').css('display','none');
        $('div.header').toggle(
            function(){$('div.header').hide('fast'); $(this).show('slow'); $('div.slide').css('display','block');},
            function(){$('div.slide').css('display','none'); $('div.header').show('fast');});
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var text = $('div.cont');
        $('div.slide').toggle(
            function(){$('div.slide').hide('fast'); $(this).show('slow'); $('div.cont').css('display','block');},
            function(){ $('div.cont').css('display','none'); $('div.slide').show('fast');});
    })
    </script>
    <style>
        .off{display: none;}
        .on{ display: block;}
        div.cont{ display: none;}
        .slide{ display:none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="projects">
        <div class="header">Websites
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Saia LTL, Inc.</a>
              <div class='cont'>a;dasndiasfhnip</div>
            </div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Insurance House</a><div class='cont'>dasndiasfhnip</div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Scandinavian Collectors Club</a><div class='cont'>dasndiasfhnip</div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Casey Sills Photography</a><div class='cont'>dasndiasfhnip</div></div></div>
        <div class="header">Personal Projects
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">cTV</a><div class='cont'>dasndiasfhnip</div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">PoE DPS calculator</a><div class='cont'>dasndiasfhnip</div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">tSlide</a><div class='cont'>dasndiasfhnip</div></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

i would prefer this one just try it

Comment: this will help you much more, if anything else you prefer  ---  just add as a comment, please copy this full code and try ok

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    var sign = 1;
        $('#projects > div.header').on('click', function() {
            if (sign == 1) {
                $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
                $(this).children().slideDown(400);
                $(this).siblings().slideUp(400);
            }
            else {
                $(this).children().slideUp(400);
                $(this).siblings().slideDown(400);
                $(this).css({
                    'height': '29px',
                    'z-index': '2'
                });
            }
            sign = sign*-1;
        });
        $('div.slide').click(function(){
            $('div.cont').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        div.cont{ display: none;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="projects">
        <div class="header">Websites</div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Saia LTL, Inc.</a>
              <div class='cont'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Insurance House</a><div class='cont'></div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Scandinavian Collectors Club</a><div class='cont'></div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">Casey Sills Photography</a><div class='cont'></div></div>
        <div class="header">Personal Projects</div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">cTV</a><div class='cont'></div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">PoE DPS calculator</a><div class='cont'></div></div>
            <div class='slide'><a href="#">tSlide</a><div class='cont'></div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

i just tried adding a class to siblings to denote them specifically ---- is it u are looking I'm happy or anything else in particular please comment me    ----- thankyou

Comment: sorry boss, try this one it will help i forgot to paste your original edited code, sorry change  $('#projects > div:not(.header)').on('click', function() to  $('#projects >
 div:header').on('click', function()

Comment: yet it's not working, try copy -> paste your code from above snippet and check it please. I've tried in FF and chrome.